# Checking minimum version of required PHP for a program?

Tags: php

One of the points of a good PHP application is the availability on the most major runtimes.

Think about the time that you want to release your PHP application to the public. We should mention the minimum version of the PHP runtime that application depends on it!

We can check the functions,etc from http://php.net to determine the minimum required version of PHP that the the function works well on it.

But if you face a big project,It is so stupid to check lines,one by one...

Finally i'm looking for a tool that i can copy the PHP source code directly into it,and that gives me only a number of the minimum required PHP version;So i can mention it on the release website as minimum dependency.

Do you know one? Or is there any alternative solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Just document the minimum version you've tested your application with. While it might work with earlier versions, you can't be sure, so don't make the claim.

Comment: that would have to be psychic tool, to archive that.

Comment: @Barmar I agree with you but i am developing programs in a country which Hosting(s) are so lazy(you guessed it,Iran :D) thru updating components to a optimal version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a tool does actually exist: you can find it [on github](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility). However, it doesn't check dependencies for you, just the minimum version of PHP that is required for the codebase

Comment: That's actually good tool,but do you know a simpler tool such as an online copy/paste one?

Comment: No, I don't know of an online copy/paste tool: I suspect it isn't practical for many PHP applications that comprise large numbers of files, when a tool like that I've linked is much more useful